# System.ApplicationException: Error in the application in DeleteTimerNative

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

In our code we have a timer which will check whether the server is connected or not. If it is not connected will try to reconnect the server.

The code is as below

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   timer.Stop();
   if (timer.Interval != serverTimeOut)
   {
     timer.Interval = serverTimeOut;
   }

   timer.Start();
   //below the code to check whether server connected or not

}
```

We are getting the exception like

```
Class: System.Threading.TimerBase
Function: DeleteTimerNative
Exception: System.ApplicationException: Error in the application.
   at System.Threading.TimerBase.DeleteTimerNative(SafeHandle notifyObject)
   at System.Threading.TimerBase.Dispose()
   at System.Threading.Timer.Dispose()
   at System.Timers.Timer.set_Enabled(Boolean value)
   at System.Timers.Timer.Stop()
   at ServerConnection.timer_Elapsed(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

In the elapsed event we are stopping the timer and changing the interval and again will start timer. Is this steps will cause any exception?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you stopping and starting the timer and setting the interval.  You should just check if the server is connected.

**Update**

You are stopping the timer, which deletes the native timer inside of the event.  Not a great idea.  Can't you just set the interval without stopping and starting.

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   if (timer.Interval != serverTimeOut)
     timer.Interval = serverTimeOut;

   //below the code to check whether server connected or not

}
```

Comment: Actually if the server get disconnected we are changing the timer interval to a some large value, ie the time to get reconnect the server, sothat only after that the elapsed event will get triggered. So once its get connected we need to change the value to server timeout itself.

Comment: Actually i found an exception in one SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793726/net-3-5-c-sharp-bug-with-system-timer-system- objectdisposedexception-cannot-ac  So i am just asking whether this one may be the cause in my case also , since in the exception details its only mentioning Application exception only.

Comment: if we are changing the interval without stopping it, will it call elapsed event according to interval?

Comment: Yes, according to documentation.

Comment: Thanks.. elapsed event is getting triggered. Actually i can't recreate this in our environment. Will check this..